# Powerpoint Using external audio during slide recording

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, recording, slideshow

I have the following issue with Powerpoint.
I have a pre-recorded audio file which i want to use in powerpoint presentation.The presentation would be an autoplay presentation so the 
timing of objects in the slides are critical.
I found the slide recording tool but the problem is that it does not allow to play external audio during the recording so i can not make the timing by record the clickings.Insted if it makes an audio narration recording than delete my attached audio.
How can i overcome this?I know i can make the timing by myself(timing manually) but it contains a lot of elements so it would takes a lot of time to counting and calculate it.

Thank you for your help